# Does the nesting of an 'unsafe' scope affects performance?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I would like to ask if the first example is somehow slower than the second example.

Example 1: for, unsafe, unsafe, unsafe, etc

```
for (var i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
    unsafe
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Example 2: unsafe, for

```
unsafe
{
    for (var i = 0; i < ...; i++)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Nowhere [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(unsafe_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.7.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) this aspect is being covered.

**Question:**

Can someone assume than the location of an `unsafe` code block does not affect performance ?

Comment: there's no difference in performance, unsafe only allows "unsafe stuff" that the compiler would prevent otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They produce the exact same IL code so no performance difference

nested:
[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSwG4CGATpgB6YC8mAAwBuZixIAzAPbdaHbmAHCRmJQB5MCIaLUBqPfXESCEs5mPnMAVwB2AZ3aSApoV57+YVQF9LpXygsAd5AA===)

c#

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        var x = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {            
            unsafe { x+=i; }
        }
    }
}
```

IL

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 20 (0x14)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32,
            [1] int32
        )

        IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0001: stloc.0
        IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0003: stloc.1
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0004: br.s IL_000e
        // loop start (head: IL_000e)
            IL_0006: ldloc.0
            IL_0007: ldloc.1
            IL_0008: add
            IL_0009: stloc.0
            IL_000a: ldloc.1
            IL_000b: ldc.i4.1
            IL_000c: add
            IL_000d: stloc.1

            IL_000e: ldloc.1
            IL_000f: ldc.i4.s 100
            IL_0011: blt.s IL_0006
        // end loop

        IL_0013: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2070
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

surrounding:
[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSwG4CGATpgB6YC8mAAwBuZixIBXAHYBndgDMApkxQT1mBQHtutDtzADhIzIYA8mBENGmA1LfriNJAs5ZO3pHrf5gxaz0wAXw9SEICScKCgA==)

c#

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        var x = 0;
        unsafe {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {            
                x+=i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IL

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 20 (0x14)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32,
            [1] int32
        )

        IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0001: stloc.0
        IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0003: stloc.1
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0004: br.s IL_000e
        // loop start (head: IL_000e)
            IL_0006: ldloc.0
            IL_0007: ldloc.1
            IL_0008: add
            IL_0009: stloc.0
            IL_000a: ldloc.1
            IL_000b: ldc.i4.1
            IL_000c: add
            IL_000d: stloc.1

            IL_000e: ldloc.1
            IL_000f: ldc.i4.s 100
            IL_0011: blt.s IL_0006
        // end loop

        IL_0013: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2070
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```